# How, as a spiritual person do you differentiate your Intuition from Holy Spirit's guidance?

Tags: pneumatology, providence

Is there some biblical verses that would support how one could differentiate spiritual guidance with our own intuition? By mistake we (at least, I) do think sometimes take decision based on my own wish without knowing if that is what God wants when we are satisfied with the the direction we move. How do you help yourself in this regard?

Comment: [John 14:26;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/john/14.26?lang=eng#25) [Galatians 5:22-23;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/gal/5.22-23?lang=eng#21) God speaks through his spirit, who communicates through emotions, not through thoughts. Intuition is in your head, sometimes in your gut, but the Spirit is in your heart.

Comment: cf. [1 Cor 14:33](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+14%3A33&version=RSVCE).

Comment: There are many such verses - eg Heb 4:12, Rom 12:1-2.  You are right to doubt the fitness of this question for the forum as is.  It may have a chance of staying open if you restrict it's scope to a particular denominational or doctrinal viewpoint, but even then it would be quite broad. I suggest you research the issue a little more and re-write your question (which in essence is a pretty worth-while one indeed) to be more tightly focused.

Comment: I think this is an exact duplicate: [How does one discern between thoughts inspired by the Holy Spirit and those produced from themselves](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16215)

Answer (score 2):

Our thoughts can easily deceive us even to think what we believe is the will of God or the speaking of the Holy Spirit.

> **2 Thessalonians 2:11-12** And for this cause **God shall send them strong delusion, that they should believe a lie**:
>   12 That they all might be damned who believed not the truth, but had pleasure in unrighteousness.

Until we come to a full knowledge and unity in the faith of Christ, we are apt to be deceived.

> **Ephesians 4:12-14** For the perfecting of the saints, for the work of the ministry, for the edifying of the body of Christ:
>   13 Till we all come in the **unity** of the faith, and of the knowledge of the Son of God, unto a **perfect man**, unto the measure of the stature of the fulness of Christ:
>   14 That we henceforth **be no more children**, tossed to and fro, and **carried about with every wind of doctrine, by the sleight of men, and cunning craftiness, whereby they lie in wait to deceive**;

If we hold onto our idols, whatever it be whether the authority of scribes, false teachers, or our own sinful desires, God will answer us according to our folly.

> **Ezekiel 14:3-6** Son of man, these men have set up their **idols in their heart**, and put the stumblingblock of their iniquity before their face: should I be enquired of at all by them?
>   4 Therefore speak unto them, and say unto them, Thus saith the Lord God; Every man of the house of Israel that setteth up his idols in his heart, and putteth the stumblingblock of his iniquity before his face, and cometh to the prophet; **I the Lord will answer him that cometh according to the multitude of his idols**;
>   5 That I may take the house of Israel in their own heart, because they are all estranged from me through their idols.
>   6 Therefore say unto the house of Israel, Thus saith the Lord God; Repent, and turn yourselves from your idols; and turn away your faces from all your abominations.

John's letters are written as an assurance for those people who think and act according to the Holy Spirit, telling us what it is to be a perfect man of God.

Excerpts:

> **1 John 2:3-5** And hereby we do know that we know him, if we keep his commandments.
>   4 He that saith, I know him, and keepeth not his commandments, is a liar, and the truth is not in him.
>   5 But whoso keepeth his word, in him verily is the love of God perfected: hereby know we that we are in him.
>
> **1 John 2:9** He that saith he is in the light, and hateth his brother, is in darkness even until now.
>
> **1 John 2:15** Love not the world, neither the things that are in the world. If any man love the world, the love of the Father is not in him.
>
> **1 John 2:26** These things have I written unto you concerning them that seduce you.
>   27 But the **anointing which ye have received of him abideth in you, and ye need not that any man teach you**: but as the same anointing teacheth you of all things, and is truth, and is no lie, and even as it hath taught you, ye shall abide in him.

Until then, let us take consolation in the counsel of James:

> **James 1:2-4** My brethren, count it all joy when ye fall into divers temptations;
>   3 Knowing this, that the trying of your faith worketh patience.
>   4 But let patience have her perfect work, that ye may be perfect and entire, wanting nothing.